# When using longtable, my table counter starts from 2 rather than 1. Why?

Tags: tables, numbering, longtable

When using `longtable`, my table counter starts from 2 rather than 1. Why?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,longtable}
%\extrarowheight5pt

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}@{}}
\toprule
Options
    & Values
        & Descriptions\\
\midrule
%
\verb|PtNameMath|
    & {\color{blue}\verb|true|}, \verb|false|
        &   whether the node label is in math mode.\\
%
\bottomrule 
\end{longtable}
\caption{\texttt{\textbackslash pstGeonode} options.}
\label{tab:GeoNodeOptions}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}@{}}
\toprule
Options
    & Values
        & Descriptions\\
\midrule
%
\verb|PtNameMath|
    & {\color{blue}\verb|true|}, \verb|false|
        &   whether the node label is in math mode.\\
%
\bottomrule 
\caption{\texttt{\textbackslash pstGeonode} options.}
\label{tab:GeoNodeOptions}
\end{longtable}    

\end{document}
```

is perfectly working and the result is:

[image]

The issue of the wrong caption number is due to the fact that you nested a `longtable` environment into a `table` one and this increase twice the counter.

Citing the documentation:

> It also shares some features with
>   the table environment. In particular it uses the same counter, table, and has a
>   similar `\caption` command.